# What do you call a home page on an app?

Tags: ios-appstore

Could it be called landing, or profile, or main ? I am not sure what these are called on an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/first-launch-experience/), the screen after the Launch screen is called the **first screen**.  Not very exciting, huh.  I've also heard/seen it as **home screen**.

> A launch screen appears the moment your app starts, giving the impression that your app is fast and responsive, while allowing initial content to load. This screen is quickly replaced by the first screen of your app...

Comment: Not very exciting indeed :)